# A sonar continuously emits x(t), a general but known waveform and is reflected by a target. hypothetical question

Tags: acoustics, signal-processing

A sonar continuously emits x(t), a general but known waveform that is reflected by a target and received by the sonar.  Both the sonar and the target move in  the 3-dimensional space in a general but known manner.  That is the positions of the sonar and the target are known.  What would be the relation between and the transmitted and received  signasl?  What would happen if the sound speed, sonar speed and the target speed are all comparable?  Is it possible that the received signal contains something like multipath?  that is some past signal points of different times are received at the same time?  Like receiving multiple balls thrown at different times being received at the same time.

Comment: You're asking a LOT of questions there!  Do you really want to model a sonar platform moving at Mach 1.5?  Are you trying to derive motion or position (or both)?

Comment: I am not or rather did not want to say that the platform is moving at Mach speeds or any thing.  I just wanted to say that let us not put any assumptions on the positions that all the things can take.  I said sonar only as an example.  Basically some radiation is happening, both source and target are changing their positions.   What are the general equations for transmitted and received waveforms - not putting any assumptions on the speeds involved.  Thanks.